# cant access react-router params from parent route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router version `6.2.1`. My router is setup like so in a `Routes` component:

```js
const routes = isLoggedIn => [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: isLoggedIn ? <DashboardLayout /> : <Navigate to={LOGIN} /> ,
    children: [
      // redirect to homepage on null route (e.g. localhost:3000 with no trailing '/')
      { path: '', element: <Navigate to = {HOME} /> },
      { path: HOME, element: <Home /> },
      { path: LIBRARY,
        element: <Library/>,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':itemId',
            element: <ItemView/>
          }
        ] 
      }
  }
]

export default function Routes(props) {
  const loginStatus = props.loginStatus === LOGGED_IN;
  const routing = useRoutes(routes(loginStatus));

  return (
    <>
      {routing}
    </>
  );
}
```

I would like to access the `itemId` param in the url from a component that is in the `Library` component which is a parent route to the itemId. If i call the useParams hook from that parent route I do not see the itemId param. Why is this the case? Am i using the wrong version of react-router? According to this github pr I believe parent routes should have access to all params:
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/pull/7963

Comment: "If i call the useParams hook from that parent route I do not see the itemId param. Why is this the case?" The `useParams` hook can see only the route params declared above them. This is generally just how React works; data flows down. If a parent component cares about what I child component "knows" then it should pass a callback down for the child to call and pass data up the tree. The "all params" bit is this from the docs: "Child routes inherit all params from their parent routes."

Comment: Have a look at the github pr i linked from the react-router repo. they have made the change that i am after

Comment: Ok, took a second look and read more of the conversation. I think you are correct. ***BUT*** the PR looks to only have been merged into the `dev` branch, not `main`, so it seems currently it's not possible but will in a future release. The PR was merged back in September and `dev` is only 2 commits behind `main` though, so maybe it's in there?

Comment: From what I can tell, accessing all the route params within a set of nested routes is working in RRDv6.2.1. I then tested with your routes config and see it working. https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-access-react-router-params-from-parent-route-gjs5i The parent `Library` component logs the `itemId` route param of the nested route.